# Add a progress bar to boot function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, progress, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to add a progress bar to a bootstrap function in R.
I tried to make the example function as simple as possible (hence i'm using mean in this example).

```
library(boot)
v1 <- rnorm(1000)
rep_count = 1

m.boot <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices]
  setWinProgressBar(pb, rep_count)
  rep_count <- rep_count + 1
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
  mean(d, na.rm = T) 
  }

tot_rep <- 200
pb <- winProgressBar(title = "Bootstrap in progress", label = "",
                     min = 0, max = tot_rep, initial = 0, width = 300)
b <- boot(v1, m.boot, R = tot_rep)
close(pb)
```

The bootstrap functions properly, but the problem is that the value of `rep_count` does not increase in the loop and the progress bar stays frozen during the process.

If I check the value of `rep_count` after the bootstrap is complete, it is still 1.

What am i doing wrong? maybe the boot function does not simply insert the `m.boot` function in a loop and so the variables in it are not increased?

Thank you.

Comment: The [package `pbapply`](https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply) is an easy way to show a progress bar for any task of applying a function using the `apply` family. https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply . If you can use your `m.boot` inside some form of `apply`, this is would be really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **pbapply** package was designed to work with vectorized functions. There are 2 ways to achieve that in the context of this question: (1) write a wrapper as was suggested, which will not produce the same object of class `'boot'`; (2) alternatively, the line `lapply(seq_len(RR), fn)` can be written as `pblapply(seq_len(RR), fn)`. Option 2 can happen either by locally copying/updating the `boot` function as shown in the example below, or asking the package maintainer, Brian Ripley, if he would consider adding a progress bar directly or through **pbapply** as dependency.

My solution (changes indicated by comments):

```
library(boot)
library(pbapply)
boot2 <- function (data, statistic, R, sim = "ordinary", stype = c("i", 
    "f", "w"), strata = rep(1, n), L = NULL, m = 0, weights = NULL, 
    ran.gen = function(d, p) d, mle = NULL, simple = FALSE, ..., 
    parallel = c("no", "multicore", "snow"), ncpus = getOption("boot.ncpus", 
        1L), cl = NULL) 
{
call <- match.call()
stype <- match.arg(stype)
if (missing(parallel)) 
    parallel <- getOption("boot.parallel", "no")
parallel <- match.arg(parallel)
have_mc <- have_snow <- FALSE
if (parallel != "no" && ncpus > 1L) {
    if (parallel == "multicore") 
        have_mc <- .Platform$OS.type != "windows"
    else if (parallel == "snow") 
        have_snow <- TRUE
    if (!have_mc && !have_snow) 
        ncpus <- 1L
    loadNamespace("parallel")
}
if (simple && (sim != "ordinary" || stype != "i" || sum(m))) {
    warning("'simple=TRUE' is only valid for 'sim=\"ordinary\", stype=\"i\", n=0', so ignored")
    simple <- FALSE
}
if (!exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) 
    runif(1)
seed <- get(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)
n <- NROW(data)
if ((n == 0) || is.null(n)) 
    stop("no data in call to 'boot'")
temp.str <- strata
strata <- tapply(seq_len(n), as.numeric(strata))
t0 <- if (sim != "parametric") {
    if ((sim == "antithetic") && is.null(L)) 
        L <- empinf(data = data, statistic = statistic, stype = stype, 
            strata = strata, ...)
    if (sim != "ordinary") 
        m <- 0
    else if (any(m < 0)) 
        stop("negative value of 'm' supplied")
    if ((length(m) != 1L) && (length(m) != length(table(strata)))) 
        stop("length of 'm' incompatible with 'strata'")
    if ((sim == "ordinary") || (sim == "balanced")) {
        if (isMatrix(weights) && (nrow(weights) != length(R))) 
            stop("dimensions of 'R' and 'weights' do not match")
    }
    else weights <- NULL
    if (!is.null(weights)) 
        weights <- t(apply(matrix(weights, n, length(R), 
            byrow = TRUE), 2L, normalize, strata))
    if (!simple) 
        i <- index.array(n, R, sim, strata, m, L, weights)
    original <- if (stype == "f") 
        rep(1, n)
    else if (stype == "w") {
        ns <- tabulate(strata)[strata]
        1/ns
    }
    else seq_len(n)
    t0 <- if (sum(m) > 0L) 
        statistic(data, original, rep(1, sum(m)), ...)
    else statistic(data, original, ...)
    rm(original)
    t0
}
else statistic(data, ...)
pred.i <- NULL
fn <- if (sim == "parametric") {
    ran.gen
    data
    mle
    function(r) {
        dd <- ran.gen(data, mle)
        statistic(dd, ...)
    }
}
else {
    if (!simple && ncol(i) > n) {
        pred.i <- as.matrix(i[, (n + 1L):ncol(i)])
        i <- i[, seq_len(n)]
    }
    if (stype %in% c("f", "w")) {
        f <- freq.array(i)
        rm(i)
        if (stype == "w") 
            f <- f/ns
        if (sum(m) == 0L) 
            function(r) statistic(data, f[r, ], ...)
        else function(r) statistic(data, f[r, ], pred.i[r, 
            ], ...)
    }
    else if (sum(m) > 0L) 
        function(r) statistic(data, i[r, ], pred.i[r, ], 
            ...)
    else if (simple) 
        function(r) statistic(data, index.array(n, 1, sim, 
            strata, m, L, weights), ...)
    else function(r) statistic(data, i[r, ], ...)
}
RR <- sum(R)
res <- if (ncpus > 1L && (have_mc || have_snow)) {
    if (have_mc) {
        parallel::mclapply(seq_len(RR), fn, mc.cores = ncpus)
    }
    else if (have_snow) {
        list(...)
        if (is.null(cl)) {
            cl <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(rep("localhost", 
              ncpus))
            if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") 
              parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(cl)
            res <- pblapply(seq_len(RR), fn, cl=cl)
            parallel::stopCluster(cl)
            res
        }
        else pblapply(seq_len(RR), fn, cl=cl)
    }
}
else pblapply(seq_len(RR), fn) #### changed !!!
t.star <- matrix(, RR, length(t0))
for (r in seq_len(RR)) t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]]
if (is.null(weights)) 
    weights <- 1/tabulate(strata)[strata]
boot.return(sim, t0, t.star, temp.str, R, data, statistic, 
    stype, call, seed, L, m, pred.i, weights, ran.gen, mle)
}
## Functions not exported by boot
isMatrix <- boot:::isMatrix
index.array <- boot:::index.array
boot.return <- boot:::boot.return
## Now the example
m.boot <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices]
  mean(d, na.rm = T) 
}
tot_rep <- 200
v1 <- rnorm(1000)
b <- boot2(v1, m.boot, R = tot_rep)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but i don't think that the maintainer of the package is interested in adding any progress bar natively, as this will, inevitably, slow down the performance of the `boot` function. Nevertheless, this may be an elegant solution using a copy of the `boot` function, as you did!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the package [`progress`](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) as below:

```
library(boot)
library(progress)

v1 <- rnorm(1000)

#add progress bar as parameter to function
m.boot <- function(data, indices, prog) {
  
  #display progress with each run of the function
  prog$tick()
  
  d <- data[indices]
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
  mean(d, na.rm = T) 
  
}

tot_rep <- 200

#initialize progress bar object
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = tot_rep + 1) 

#perform bootstrap
boot(data = v1, statistic = m.boot, R = tot_rep, prog = pb)
```

I haven't quite figured out yet why it's necessary to set the number of iterations for `progress_bar` to be +1 the total bootstrap replicates (parameter `R`), but this is what was necessary in my own code, otherwise it throws an error. It seems like the bootstrap function is run one more time than you specify in parameter `R`, so if the progress bar is set to only run `R` times, it thinks the job is finished before it really is.

Comment: The reason why one has to set `total = R+1` is probably because boot() calculates R + 1 statistics - one for the actual data (t0) and R statistics t for the R bootstrap samples. Hence effectively, boot() is called R+1 times.

Answer (score 2):

The increased `rep_count` is a local variable and lost after each function call. In the next iteration the function gets `rep_count` from the global environment again, i.e., its value is 1.

You can use `<<-`:

```
rep_count <<- rep_count + 1
```

This assigns to the `rep_count` first found on the search path outside the function. Of course, using `<<-` is usually not recommended because side effects of functions should be avoided, but here you have a legitimate use case. However, you should probably wrap the whole thing in a function to avoid a side effect on the global environment.

There might be better solutions ...

Comment: I think this is the more _correct_ way, from a programmer's point of view. But due to my scarce ability in programming, i think i will stick with the solution provided below. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need advanced programming skills to change this one line of code.

Comment: You are right, I just like using someone's else functions, as i think that they are programmed better than mine. For example, being able to use the `pbapply` package adds the ability to change style and type of the progress bar just in seconds. I am trying to find a way to use `pbapply` with `bootstrap`. But maybe someone will find the solution before I do!

Comment: If you want to use an `apply` type function, you can't use `boot`. You'd have to write your own bootstrapping (which wouldn't be hard and possibly be educational).

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a possible solution. This merges the answer of @Roland with the convenience of the `pbapply` package, using its functions `startpb()`, `closepb()`, etc..

```
library(boot)
library(pbapply)

v1 <- rnorm(1000)
rep_count = 1
tot_rep = 200

m.boot <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices]
  setpb(pb, rep_count)
  rep_count <<- rep_count + 1
  Sys.sleep(0.01)                #Just to slow down the process
  mean(d, na.rm = T) 
}

pb <- startpb(min = 0, max = tot_rep)
b <- boot(v1, m.boot, R = tot_rep)
closepb(pb)
rep_count = 1
```

As previously suggested, wrapping everything in a function avoids messing with the `rep_count` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar from the package `dplyr` works well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(boot)

v1 <- rnorm(1000)

m.boot <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices]
  p$tick()$print()  # update progress bar
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
  mean(d, na.rm = T) 
}

tot_rep <- 200
p <- progress_estimated(tot_rep+1)  # init progress bar
b <- boot(v1, m.boot, R = tot_rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `pbapply`

```
library(boot)
library(pbapply)
v1 <- rnorm(1000)
rep_count = 1

# your m.boot function ....
m.boot <- function(data, indices) {
                                   d <- data[indices]
                                   mean(d, na.rm = T) 
                                   }

# ... wraped in `bootfunc`
bootfunc <- function(x) { boot(x, m.boot, R = 200) }

# apply function to v1 , returning progress bar
pblapply(v1, bootfunc)

# > b <- pblapply(v1, bootfunc)
# >   |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% Elapsed time: 02s
```

Comment: I have a problem. This function runs the bootstrap function multiple times, obtaining a b object that is not a single bootstrap object, but a vector of 1000 bootstrap objects. I think that the pbapply does not work well with this function maybe.

Comment: Indeed @fzara, I'm thinking about this and I'll come back with a work around this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meanwhile i found a workaround, hope it is useful for you too.